# npm git error code 0 while installing phonegap

Tags: git, cordova, npm

While installing phonegap its giving below error,

```
$npm install -g phonegap
    npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/apache/cordova-lib.git) fatal: un
    able to connect to github.com:
    npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/apache/cordova-lib.git) github.co
    m[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=No error
    npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
    npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=No error
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:647:15)
    npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
    npm ERR! cwd D:\TSC Project
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
    npm ERR! code 128
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     D:\TSC Project\npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I installed git also after installing git, still giving error

Comment: `unable to connect to github.com:` check that ssh key is present in both your local and public key is present in your github account or if you have firewall on first disable it and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, I installed git, still it given error, after i changed npm registry. Now its working fine.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.eu
npm install phonegap -g
```